# Swift - Append parameters to NSURL before loading it to the UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, nsurl

I'm trying to append the `deviceToken` to the URL before the `webView loadRequest` so that I can `GET` the value using **PHP** script. My problem is, the function `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`, which holds the deviceToken value, is fired/runs last. The `deviceToken` is appended **after** the `loadRequest`, which is not the way I needed.

Is there any way for it to be passed before it loads?

Comment: There isn't really a delegate or a function to intercept this. The only way I see you could do this is either by reloading the webview with the new NSURL after changing it with the device token or by getting the device token first and only then load the UIWebview.

Comment: @TedHuinink I've created a function for webView.loadRequest. Normally, it is called inside the viewDidLoad function. Where should I call it then so that I can call the function for getting the device token first?

Comment: @TedHuinink First of all, sorry for the question. I'm just a newbie in Swift. Thank you for giving me an idea, I've done it. I have read about dispatch time and used it to reload my page with the device token. Thank you.

Comment: Glad that you got a general idea from my comment. Would appreciate it if you could write in an answer what you did to fix it and mark it as correct in case someone else faces the same issue!

Comment: @Scar you need to create(for example `reloadWebWithToken:token`) and call a method of your `WebViewController` from the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method in `appDelegete`. In the `reloadWebWithToken:token` method append the token to URL and then call `webView.loadRequest` with new URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved my problem:

**NOTE:**

The following code may not be as polished as yours. I'm still starting to learn Swift so pardon me for "messy" code.

Here's my ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

//Reference to my AppDelegate 

        let ad = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        ad.regDevTok()
        loadAddressURL()

        //reload
        let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 5 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            var url = NSURL(string: "http://yourSite/sampleIndex.php?token=\(token)")
            var requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!,
                cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
                timeoutInterval: 3.0)

            self.webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
        }
    }

    //Setting up GUI of webview
    func loadAddressURL() {
        var myURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.yourSite.com/sampleIndex.php")
        var reqURL = NSURLRequest(URL : myURL!)
        webView.loadRequest(reqURL)
        NSLog("loadAddressURL")
    }
```

And here's my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        //var token was initiated as a global variable
        token = deviceToken.hexString()
    }

func regDevTok(){
        // Device Token
        let deviceToken = defaults.objectForKey("DeviceToken") as! String?
        if (deviceToken == nil) {
            let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
            let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }   
    }
```

Thank you to sir @Ted Huinink and sir @Mahesh for giving me ideas to come up with the solution.